# How to ignore SSL error in Nuxt.js from OSS upgrading?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have upgrading OSS versions in my nuxt project.
Basically, I used "nuxt":"2.0.0" version and I have upgraded latest version "nuxt":"2.14.7".
It was no problem to open my web apps in browser but warning is occurred like following.

```
Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
```

I thought that its warning message is solved setting "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0" in nuxt.confing.ts(my language is TypeScript).
So,my put the "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0" to .env file and in nuxt.confing.ts, I made following code.

```
    export default {env:process.env}
```

I ran this code, same error message was still occurred.
Could anyone advise me?

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55440261/nuxt-js-problem-with-server-side-api-call-with-https

Comment: Thanks for comment. I have already tried to the site you mentioned.

Comment: I really don't understand why this error message occurred after OSS upgrading. And I have searched and tried many times but error never disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really tried to fix the issue, finally I fix it.
But actually, I don't know why my solution is successed.
I put following code in package.json at scripts of "dev".

```
"scripts": {
"dev:all": "npm run serve & npm run storybook",
"dev": "export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=1 && nuxt-ts --env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=1",}
```

I keep to search about issue.